# Блок фиксированной ширины внутри row блока bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Коллеги, добрый день. Не подскажите, где мне можно посмотреть пример реализации, макета на Bootstrap, где после background элемента (первая секция), визуально идёт другой слой, без изображения (вторая секция), но между первой и второй секцией вставлен слой с фиксированной шириной, внутри которой будет некий текст.

Пример макета во вложении.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где копать?

[image: макет на Bootstrap]

Comment: Как вариант, это добавить добавить к CSS второй секции:
`position:relative`

и внутри добавить слой у которого будет следующий css код:
`position:absolute;
background:#2BF4A1;
top:-50%;
right:0;
width:100%;
z-index:99999;`

но правильное это решение, с точки зрения использования возможностей фреймворка Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не самое элегантное и правильно решение.
Создаете блок с текстов не в синей секции, а в белой, и сдвигаете с помощью margin-top вниз, примерно как форма обратной связи здесь http://trbogdan.tk/4500/